# Create new pop up window in ASP.NET from server side

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

On a button click, I need to retrieve the values of HTML from database (saved as a string object in C# code) and create a new pop up window and render the HTML values to pop up from the server side.

Can you please help me on how can I do this ?

Comment: when button is clicked, hit server via ajax, get popup data, create new popup window client side, populate it with results from server ajax call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to accomplish it.

You can use jquery to open an iframe modal window. Server side add an aspx page with a placeholder control on it. In the PageLoad event of that page read the html content from database and set the text property of the literal control with the string you just read from database and then add the literal to the place holder

```
Literal literal = new Literal();
literal.text = myHtml // html read from database       
MyPlaceholder.Controls.Add(literal);
```

In the page where you want to open the modal add the following code and set iframe source to the page you just created

```
<div id="dialog">
    <iframe id="myIframe" src=""></iframe>
</div>
<button id="dialogBtn">Open Dialog</button>


$("#dialog").dialog({
autoOpen: false,
modal: true,
height: 600,
open: function(ev, ui){
         $('#myIframe').attr('src','http://www.example.com/mypage.aspx')
      }
});

$('#dialogBtn').click(function(){
$('#dialog').dialog('open');
});
```

Comment: Than you for the suggestion. I did it with with having a placeholder in new aspx and rendering like .
string data = "<div>......</div>"
Adding a div on plain popup such as <div id="div1" runat="server"></div>
and then using control.InnterHtml = data;

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it using a new aspx page like described in answer 1 but did not have to use jquery. I just put this into the aspx page I was calling it from:

`<a href="http://www.example.com/mypage.aspx'" onclick="window.open('mypage.aspx','popup','width=450,height=500,toolbar=no,directories=no,location=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,status=no,left=0,top=0'); return false">Info</a>`